# Switch cases for programming keys on keyboard. Does this seem correct so far?

Tags: c, pic

I want to assign each keyboard key with a character and have function keys such as shift + a to give A or Ctlr + Alt + Delete ect. Does this seem good so far and if yes or no, what would you suggest?

```
// TO EDIT CASES
    int cases ;
    switch (cases)
{

// LETTERS & OTHERS
    case 0: // a A
        gesture_simple() ;
        if (GESTURE == 1) {
            BUFFER[1 + NB_TOUCH] = 0x14 ;
        }
        if (GESTURE == 5) {
            T_REL = 0x14 ;
        }
        RSOUT "A ", Int STAGE, 13;
        send_code() ;

case 67: // Left CTRL
        gesture_simple() ;
        if (GESTURE == 1) {
            BUFFER[0] = BUFFER[0] | 0b00000001 ;
        }
        if (GESTURE == 5) {
            BUFFER[0] = BUFFER[0] & 0b11111110 ;
        }
        printf("Left Ctrl", 13) ;
        send_code() ;
```

Essentially, I am trying to build a keyboard. There are 96 keys and each key has a character or function. How can I do mapping and how can I program each key so that when I press a button, it will enter the character and in an RS Terminal print the key pressed?

Comment: Maybe you miss a `break;` in the end of each `case` block?

Comment: Hi there, I do not really understand? and why do we use a break ; ?

Comment: A `break` ends the switch statement. In your posted code if you get into `case 0:` and execute that code block then you'll continue executing the code block in `case 67:` because the first code block doesn't end with a `break`

Comment: Okay thank you, I will apply it. 

How can I get each key to print in serial terminal? I don't think it's print f?

Comment: a good coding style is to use always a 'default' statement.

Comment: I could'nt understand this line: RSOUT "A ", Int STAGE, 13;

Comment: I understand and yes perhaps I need to add it for default. How can I make it so that I can print in the serial terminal? In Proton BASIC RS is a function that lets you print to serial but I do not know what the equivalent is

Comment: Try printf(...);

Comment: Okay I will do that. So I will add a break ; and replace RsOut with printf ?

Comment: Where would the printf be printing too? The serial terminal?

Comment: And dont forget Default case at the end.

Comment: I guess you are working with a PIC controller, so printf() will use the UART. Of course you had to initialize the UART in advance.

Comment: Yes that is correct Mike. So do I initialize the UART write at the benning of everything? I use MPLAB X IDE with XC8 and MCC configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
int main(void)
{
    int cases ;

    intitUART();          //initialize the UART as you want

    //do something....

    switch (cases)
    {
        case 0: 
             //do semething....
             printf("A");         //output 'A' to UART of your PIC controller
             printf("a");         // output 'a' in ASCII
             break;

        case 1: 
             //do semething....
             printf("B");
             break;
        //.....

        case 26: 
        default:
             //do semething....
             printf("Z");
             break;
    }
}
```

I guess the MCC will help you a lot with the UART configuration.

Comment: Thanks Mike yes that make some good sense, But surely if I want lower case or uppercase letter, I will need to after a function inside the case for a and A?

Comment: Thanks again Mike. I will get back to this post once I have applied this to the code. You're very helpful :)

Comment: Tip: you really had to start with the basics in PIC programming. Write an easy programm and try to enable the UART and then watch what happens. If this post is helpful please accept/upvote.